# Function for a circular variable

Tags: matlab, variables

For instance, if you have 3pi and use `wrapTo2Pi(3pi)` it gives pi.

What I want is exactly this but instead of 0 to 2pi I want from 1 to 12 (months of the year).

So if I I have 17 I want `function(17) = 5`

Is there such a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`mod`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/mod.html)

If you want a `base 1` system (your first value is `1`) like for the month number, you have to do a `1` offset (inside then outside the function), like so:

```
mod(17-1,12)+1
ans =
     5
```

*<sub>Special thanks to [Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2586922/luis-mendo) for the correction and attention to detail.</sub>*

---

If you work with a `base 0` system (trigonometry, hours, etc ...), you don't have to do the offset, you can simplify to:

```
mod( 3*pi , 2*pi )
ans =
   3.141592653589793
```

or for hours in a day:

```
mod( 36 , 24 )
ans =
    12
```

Comment: Actually you need `mod(17-1,12)+1`, otherwise 12 gets converted to 0, not to 12

Comment: @LuisMendo. yes you're right, specifically for the case of the month. Sometimes you want the `base` to be 0 (for trigonometry or hours for example), but in this case you want a `base 1`. Thank you for the correction.